# Which node table in Drupal 6 stores the node published date, created date timestamps?

Tags: 6, nodes, database

I need to write a query to retrieve all nodes and their published dates for a Drupal 6 website and I would like to know which database table holds the nids and the timestamps. I am aware that there are 6 tables dedicated for storing info related to nodes.

I know about node_load but I do not want to use that?

Comment: can't you use views?

Comment: Nope. This is for writing a module. I need to query it directly from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node created and updated timestamps are stored in the base "node" table.

e.g

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, title, changed, created FROM {node} ORDER BY nid ASC LIMIT 10");

while($row = db_fetch_object($result)){
  // drupal_set_message($row->title);
  drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($row,1).'</pre>');
}
```